# MySQL Query: Filtering search results by tags

Tags: mysql, search

Suppose that you have a database table that works as a link between two others. In this case, a link between a book and a tag, such as "fiction" or "gardening". If we have the following dataset:

```
Book_id | tag_id
----------------
1       | 13
1       | 43
1       | 15
2       | 13
2       | 25
```

**What kind of query would you run to say "Find only the books that have links with tags 13, 43, AND 15"?** That is, the more tags you add, the smaller the number of books shown.

I hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance for your time and help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
  Book_id
FROM
  book_tags
GROUP BY
  Book_id
HAVING 
  SUM( CASE WHEN tag_id IN (13, 43, 15) THEN 1 END ) >= 3
```

You only need the books that have tags `13, 43, 15` (all of them), it returns `book_id = 1` for your result. `SUM() >= 3` specifies the total number of tags you are searching, in this case its `3`, i.e `13, 43, 15`

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79642/1)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly... Like this:

```
SELECT `Book_id` FROM `table` WHERE `tag_id` IN (13,43,25) LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
select book_table.* from book_table, link_table where book_table.id = link_table.book_id and link_table.tag_id in (13, 43, 15)
```

If you have a separate table for your books..